# Auto-scaling of agent/worker nodes in Azure Container Service [Kubernetes]

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-virtual-machine, azure-container-service

I am working with windows + kubernetes cluster on ACS (Azure Container Service). I have few queries about the auto-scaling of agents/worker nodes in ACS.

Suppose I have a cluster of 1 master and 5 worker nodes. I have 200 running pods and these pods are distributed along the 5 worker nodes and the resources of these 5 nodes are used. Now, if I deploy a new pod or scale the running pods which will requires more resources, so is there any way ACS can auto-scale the worker nodes to like 7 worker nodes based on the resource usage?

Same case, if resource usage is reduced, can ACS descale the worker nodes to 3 worker nodes from 7 nodes?

My question is not related to auto-scaling of pods as provided by kubernetes, I am talking about auto-scaling of worker/agent nodes which are managed by ACS.

Comment: is it tied to a vmscale set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is not related to auto-scaling of pods as provided by
>   kubernetes, I am talking about auto-scaling of worker/agent nodes
>   which are managed by ACS

Currently, autoscaling of agent nodes in a container service cluster is **not** supported.

For now, we can use Azure CLI2.0 to scale down or up by command `az acs scale`

For example:
 `azure acs scale -g myResourceGroup -n containerservice-myACSName --new-agent-count 10`

More information about az acs scale command, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-scale#scale-with-the-azure-cli-20).

Comment: Just check if it helps. Or what can I do for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jason. Can you confirm if there are plans to support Autoscaling of agent nodes with Kubernetes on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure-cli. The command you would need is *az acs scale*